# How to fix Type definition error in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-mvc

I am building a Spring Boot application that utilizes the com.explore.explore.entities.Spot class. but getting this error

`Type definition error: [simple type, class com.explore.explore.entities.Spot]] with root cause`

I have checked the Spot class and its dependencies, but I can't seem to find the issue. How can I fix this error and properly serialize the Spot object to JSON?

I have already tried the following steps:

- Checked that the Spot class is defined correctly, with all fields and methods properly annotated.
- Checked that any custom data types used in the Spot class are defined correctly and annotated properly.
- Checked that any dependencies used by the Spot class are present and correctly configured.

**MyController.java**

```
package com.explore.explore.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.explore.explore.entities.Spot;
import com.explore.explore.services.SpotService;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    public SpotService SpotService;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String home() {
        return "hello";
    }

    // get spots
    @GetMapping("/spots")
    // public List<Integer> getSpots() {
    // List<Integer> list;
    // list = new ArrayList<>();
    // list.add(3);
    // list.add(5);
    // return this.SpotService.getSpots();
    // }

    public List<Spot> getSpots() {
        
        List<Spot> list;
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Spot(1, "38 Block", "Near 38"));
        list.add(new Spot(0, "UNIMAll", "Near Me"));
        return list;
    }
}
```

**Spot.java**

```
package com.explore.explore.entities;

import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException;

public class Spot {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String location;

    public Spot(long id, String name, String location) {
    
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    
    }
    public Spot() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add annotations for serialization

`@JsonAutoDetect`, `@JsonProperty`, and `@JsonInclude`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class Spot {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private long id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("location")
    private String location;

    public Spot(long id, String name, String location) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Spot() {
        super();
    }

    // getters and setters here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using spring boot?
If you use spring boot ....

You can add a @getter

```
@Getter
public class Spot {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String location;

    public Spot(long id, String name, String location) {

        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;

    }
    public Spot() {
        super();
    }
}
```